# Не верная версия интерпретатора Python в виртуальном окружении

Tags: python, venv

ОС Виндовс-10

В системе был установлен Python-3.9.5

Создал виртуальное окружение с помощью venv из стандартной библиотеки (не virtualenv).

В виртуальном окружении файл `...venv_3_9_5\Scripts\python.exe` - версия 3.9.5

Обновляю системный Python до версии 3.9.6

В системе файл `...Program Files\Python39\python.exe` - версия 3.9.6

Акривирую созданное на предыдущем шаге виртуальное окружение с файлом python.exe - версии 3.9.5

```
бла-бла...venv_3_9_5/Scripts/activate.bat
```

Консоль пишет, что окружение активировано:

```
(venv_3_9_5) ...бла-бла...
```

Проверяю в виртуальном окружении версию питона, пишет версию системного питона (3.9.6), а не из venv (3.9.5)

```
(venv_3_9_5) ...бла-бла...>py
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21)
```

В чём ошибка? ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: А если вывести путь к интерпретатору `print(sys.executable)`, то будет системный питон?

Comment: `(venv_3_9_5) ...бла-бла...>py` - а если не py, а python, то какую версию напишет?

Comment: `print(sys.executable)` показывает путь к интерпретатору из виртуального окружения

Comment: Команда `python` показывает тоже системный питон.

Comment: Ну, теоретически в виртуальном окружении может быть не копия, а ссылка на системный Python. Если нужны разные версии python, я бы просто рядом еще одну поставил, а не обновлял предыдущую.

Comment: В виртуальном окружении не ссылка. Там файл `...venv_3_9_5\Scripts\python.exe - версия 3.9.5` И команда `print(sys.executable)` показывает путь к нему.

Comment: А вы удалите (или переименуйте) системный python.exe и попробуйте запустить `...venv_3_9_5\Scripts\python.exe` через cmd, посмотрите что напишет

Comment: Переименовал системный `python.exe`. Активировал окружение. Консоль сообщила, что оно активировалось `(G_venv_3_9_5) V:\Tools\Py\VIRTUALENV>`. Запускаю `py`. Пишет `No Python at 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe'`

Comment: Совсем забыл. Виртуальное окружение создавал через PyCharm, меню `Add Python Interpreter`

Comment: Сторонние библиотеки импортируются из виртуального окружения. Безошибочно. В системном питоне нет ни одной сторонней библиотеки, а окружении есть.

Comment: virtualenv созданный venv завязан на системный питон https://stackoverflow.com/a/55027588/2231972 Если нужно несколько версий одновременно используйте pyenv

Comment: А для чего тогда в виртуальном окружении файл интерпретатора `...venv_3_9_5\Scripts\python.exe` со своей версией, отличной от системного? И почему команда `print(sys.executable)` указывает именно на этот файл?

Comment: "А для чего тогда в виртуальном окружении файл интерпретатора ...venv_3_9_5\Scripts\python.exe со своей версией, отличной от системного?" - туда кладется не файл интерпретатора, а утилита py.exe ([Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)), переименованная в python.exe, которая вызывает системный python.exe. См. скриншот:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWw0H.png

Comment: Вот теперь секрет раскрыт.